# How to use DS.Store.registerAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to use the 'adapter per type' feature of ember-data. Not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug in ember-data. Basically i thought it would work like this:

```
Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
var personAdapter = DS.Adapter.create();
DS.Store.registerAdapter(Person, personAdapter );
```

The store always uses the the default adapter and not the registered 'per type adapter'
I wrote a test case to show what I mean:

```
var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;
var Person, store, adapter, personAdapter;

module("DS.Store and DS.Adapter 'adapter per type' integration test", {
  setup: function() {
    Person = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string')
  });

  adapter = DS.Adapter.create();
  personAdapter = DS.Adapter.create();

  DS.Store.registerAdapter(Person, personAdapter);
    store = DS.Store.create({ adapter: adapter });
  },

  teardown: function() {
    adapter.destroy();
    store.destroy();
  }
});


test("test function on the per type adapter", function() {

  adapter.find = function(store, type, id) {
    ok(false, "should call find on the registered 'per type adapter' not on the default one");
  };

  personAdapter.find = function(store, type, id) {
    store.load(Person, {
      'id': 1,
      'name': "My Name"
    });
  };

  var person = store.find(Person, 1);
  equal(person.get('name'), "My Name");
});
```

While debugging I noticed that the "DS.Mappable._reifyMapping" mixing explicitly checks for DS.Store and stops if the "this" is a DS.Store.

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using? This feature was added last week and is not included in http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.js yet

Comment: I use the latest version from github. I noticed that this function was introduced and I have several use cases that could benefit from.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;
var Person, StoreClass, store, adapter, personAdapter;

module("DS.Store and DS.Adapter 'adapter per type' integration test", {
  setup: function() {
    Person = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string')
    });

    adapter = DS.Adapter.create();
    personAdapter = DS.Adapter.create();

    StoreClass = DS.Store;
    StoreClass.registerAdapter(Person, personAdapter);
    store = StoreClass.create({ adapter: adapter });
  },

  teardown: function() {
    adapter.destroy();
    store.destroy();
  }
});

...
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers here are no longer valid (as of Ember Data 1.0.beta.1).

Per the [changelog](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/81f8e7c43454584b746dba8d1440904e27eb4980/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters), you now use the ModelNameAdapter syntax. For example,

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
});

App.CustomAdapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    url: 'your/custom/url'
});

App.PersonAdapter = App.CustomAdapter;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug report for this: [Per-type Adapter not respected in case of `commit`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/616)

Edit: removed inappropriate comment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it won't be fixed. That ticket just implies that it will be hard to fix.

Comment: Sorry for my negativity, but the bug asks whether it is 'desirable' to fix.