# Add extra url params per model with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
App.Providers = DS.Model.extend({    
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    logo: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('App.Products')
});

App.Products = DS.Model.extend({    
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
    provider: DS.belongsTo('App.Providers'), 
});
```

They are both using the same Adapter. However, for the Products model I want to append an extra url param (the api key) to the url. How can I extend the adapter (or the serializer?) to implement this?

So just to give you an example when I want to do a GET for providers:

```
http://example.com/ap1/v1/providers/
```

and for products:

```
http://example.com/ap1/v1/products/?api_key=1234
```

I know I can add this when I do `App.Products.find({api_key=1234})` but the problem occurs when I do:

```
var providers = App.Providers.find(1);
providers.get('products');
```

EDIT: 
I have tried to override the buildURL method in the adapter but it's not very convenient since I want to append the api_key param only for certain models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a second adapter which overrides the buildURL method. Then register that adapter for any types that should be using an api key.

```
apiAdapter = originalAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: ....
}));

Store.registerAdapter(App.Providers, apiAdatper);
```

See this post for more detail on per-type adapters: [How to use DS.Store.registerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267434/how-to-use-ds-store-registeradapter)

Comment: I've seen this somewhere else too but when I try your suggestion I get this Uncaught TypeError: Object <DS.Store:ember206> has no method 'registerAdapter' .

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to call registerAdapter on an instance of DS.Store - instead you need to call registerAdapter on the StoreClass.  Dmitry's answer has a good example  of how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267434/how-to-use-ds-store-registeradapter or see the ember-data tests here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/per_type_adapters.js