# Ember.js: How to sync model to a different namespace from the default

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

In my store.js.coffee, I'm setting the namespace for my API:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: "api/v1"
```

That's the base namespace I want to use for my ember-data API calls to Rails Active Model Serializers.

But in some API calls, I want my model to sync with an endpoint in the namespace `api/v1/admin`.

How do I do this in Ember (leaving the application default as `api/v1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer here is actually no longer valid (as of Ember Data 1.0.beta.1).

Per the [changelog](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/81f8e7c43454584b746dba8d1440904e27eb4980/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters), you now use the ModelNameAdapter syntax. For example,

```
App.AdminAsset = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
});

App.AdminAdapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    url: 'api/v1/admin'
    ...
});

App.AdminAssetAdapter = App.AdminAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [set adapters per type in ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267434/how-to-use-ds-store-registeradapter).  So create another adapter for '/admin', set the namespace on that adapter to "api/v1/admin" and then set the appropriate types to use that adapter instead:

```
App.AdminAsset = DS.Model.extend({
   ....
});

App.adminAdapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    url: "api/v1/admin"
});


App.Store.registerAdapter(App.AdminAsset, App.adminAdapter);
```